# Grouping value from left outer join

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple issue. I want to use grouping value from left outer join.
But i got exception "Object reference not set...". 
Where do i wrong and could you help me ?

My code;

```
var query = from a in aList
            join b in bList n a.id equals b.id into bJoin
            from bVal in bJon.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { a.x, a.y, a.z, bVal.x } by a.q into grp
            select new {
               q = a.q,
               ....
               x = grp.Max(max=>max.a.x)!=null ? grp.Max(max=>max.b.x) : string.Empty
            };
```

Comment: You are missing a new after the group

Comment: It should be `group new { a.x, a.y, a.z, bVal.x }...`

Comment: i forget write. there is new { a.x ... } in code.

Comment: actually if i couldn't write ```group new { ... }``` probably IDE gave error.

Comment: @devSE, either your `aList` or `bList` is null.

Comment: probably dude. so i'm using left outer join because i know this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. You can find the solution code below;

```
var query = from a in aList
            join b in bList n a.id equals b.id into bJoin
            from bVal in bJon.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { a.x, a.y, a.z, 
               newX = (bVal == null ? string.Empty : bVal.x)
            } 
            by a.q into grp
            select new {
               q = a.q,
               ....
               x = grp.Max(max=>max.a.x)!=null ? grp.Max(max=>max.newX) : string.Empty
            };
```